# Output all variables into Mako template

Tags: python, templates, mako

I don't have an easy access to the code, I'm working only with a Mako template, and I would like to know all the values that were made available to the template, which I can use.

Is there a way to add something in the template, so that the output result would contain all the variables (recursively)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [the context object](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html#mako.runtime.Context). After a minute or two of play:

```
${context.keys()}    # list of direct variable names
${context.__dict__}  # probably more along what you're looking for.
```

The entire section on the [Mako Runtime environment](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html) is probably worth reading, especially the part '[All the built in names](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html#all-the-built-in-names).' You may find the other post I just made relevant:

[Mako how to check if variable exists or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006720/pylons-mako-how-to-check-if-variable-exist-or-not/12006824#12006824)

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this I think this must help:

```
${globals()}
```

Comment: Thanks for a suggestions. But it doesn't output what I need. For example, I certainly have a variable "objects" in my template (which I can loop through), but in the text that "globals()" output, the only instance of "objects" is this one: "'__doc__': "Built-in functions, exceptions, and other objects.\n\nNoteworthy: None is the `nil' object; Ellipsis represents `...' in slices."" :)

Comment: so and what type of variable objects ?

Comment: Not variable objects, a variable named "objects". :) I can read a value objects.name, for example. I would like to have a list where I can see that I can add, for example, among other values "objects.name"'s value into my template, or at least that "objects" is accessible.

Comment: I'm using OpenERP. Don't know what framework they use. I'm just a mere template designer. :)