# pylons mako how to check if variable exist or not

Tags: pylons, mako

In django, we can do this:

```
views.py : 

    def A(request):
        context = {test : 'test'}
        return render_to_response('index.html', context , context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    def B(request):
        context = {}
        return render_to_response('index.html', context , context_instance = RequestContext(request))

index.html:

        {% if test %}
            {{ test }}
        {% endif %}
```

And have our template render without error, even if i use `method B`, where variable `'test'` does not exist, but I still can put it in the template.

I want to do the same with pylons + mako, in controller :

```
foo.py

    def A(self):
        c.test = 'test'
        return render('index.html')

    def B(self):
        return render('index.html')

index.html :

        % if c.test:
            ${'c.test'}
        % endif
```

In Django, I can do that, but in Pylons, I get an error, is there anyway to check wheter `'c.test'` exists or not?

the error : AttributeError: 'ContextObj' object has no attribute 'test'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [mako Docs on Context Variables](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html#context-variables):

```
% if someval is UNDEFINED:
    someval is: no value
% else:
    someval is: ${someval}
% endif
```

The docs describe this as **referencing variable names not in the current context**. Mako will set these variables to the value `UNDEFINED`.

I check for variables like so:

```
% if not someval is UNDEFINED:
    (safe to use someval)
```

However, if pylons/pyramid has `strict_undefined=True` setting, attempts to use the undefined variable results in a `NameError` being raised. They give a brief philisophical justification for doing it this way, instead of simply replacing un-set variables with empty strings which seems consistent with Python philosophy. Took me a while to find this, but reading that entire [section on the Mako Runtime](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/runtime.html) will clear up how Mako recieves, sets, and uses context variables.

**Edit**:
For completions sake, the documents explain the `strict_undefined` setting [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/environment.html#mako-strict-undefined). You can change this variable by setting it in one of your .ini files:

```
[app:main]
...
mako.strict_undefined = false
```

Comment: thank you, just one more question, so if im not sure that some variable exist or not , don't use strict_undefined=True ?

Comment: No, I think wrapping in a try / except block would still work in that case. I'd defer to someone more experienced, but suspect it is more about keeping a consistent coding style. I'm not sure doing it one way over the other is 'more correct'.

Comment: I added an answer that isn't dependent on strict_undefined

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue where I had multiple views using the same template and needed to test if a variable was set.  I looked at the docs chris referenced and found another way to solve this problem regardless of how `mako.strict_undefined` is set.  Essentially you call the `get()` method on the `context` object.  In your example you could do the following:

```
% if context.get('test', UNDEFINED) is not UNDEFINED:
  ${test}
% endif
```

or

```
${context.get('test', '')}
```

That will print the same as `${test}` if it exists, and print an empty string if it doesn't.

Unfortunately you can't seem to use an `in` operator on `context` which would be the most intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, so whenever you use a variable on your template that doesn't exist on your controller, pylons will raise an error, to disable the error, just put this in your environment.py :

```
config['pylons.strict_tmpl_context'] = False
```