# Pylons Mako undefined variable

Tags: python, pylons, mako

In the controller, I define 2 method:

foobar.py:

```
class foo(self):
    c.help_text = 'help'
    return render('/index.html')

class bar(self):
    return render('/index.html')
```

index.html:

```
${c.help_text}
```

This gives me an error ==> AttributeError: 'ContextObj' object has no attribute 'help_text'

After reading some mako docs, I try:

```
    % if c.help_text is UNDEFINED:
        foo
    % else:
        ${c.help_text}
    % endif
```

It also gives me an error. Then in my development.ini, I put:

```
mako.strict_undefined = false
```

after

```
[app:main]
```

This still give me an error ==> AttributeError: 'ContextObj' object has no attribute 'help_text'

Comment: see this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12006720/pylons-mako-how-to-check-if-variable-exist-or-not

Answer (score 0):

I believe your controller code is incorrect. Your first sample should either be...

```
def foo(request):
    c.help_text = 'help'
    return render('/index.html')

def bar(request):
    return render('/index.html')
```

...or...

```
class Controller(object):
    def foo(self, request):
        c.help_text = 'help'
        return render('/index.html')

    def bar(self, request):
        return render('/index.html')
```

I believe that because you have this controller code incorrect, the "c.help_text" is not actually being run in response to handling a query, but it's being handled right when you start up the application.

If you fix these errors and still have issues, can you please provide more information the error? Do you have a stack trace or an exact line number?